# nth-of-type on squarespace

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I am using Squarespace and trying to move the margin of the first `.field.text.three-digits` using "nth-of-type", but I can't get it to work right.

CSS:

```
.form-item.fields.phone:nth-of-type(3) {
  background-color: red;
  margin-left: 20%;
}
```

HTML:

```
<fieldset id="phone-yui_3_17_2_1_1531771537607_16560" class="form-item fields 
  phone">
   <div class="title">Phone</div>
   <legend>Phone</legend>
   <div class="field text three-digits" id="yui_3_17_2_1_1531936132691_509">
       <label class="caption" id="yui_3_17_2_1_1531936132691_508"><input 
        class="field-element" x-autocompletetype="phone-area-code" type="text" 
        maxlength="3" data-title="Areacode" id="yui_3_17_2_1_1531936132691_507"> 
        (###)</label>
   </div>
   <div class="field text three-digits">
       <label class="caption"><input class="field-element" x- 
        autocompletetype="phone-local-prefix" type="text" maxlength="3" data- 
        title="Prefix">###</label>
   </div>
   <div class="field text four-digits">
       <label class="caption"><input class="field-element" x- 
        autocompletetype="phone-local-suffix" type="text" maxlength="4" data- 
        title="Line">####</label>
   </div>
</fieldset>
```

Thanks!

Comment: If you want to apply your css to `nth-of-type(3)`, then its working fine.

Comment: I understand it's suppose to work, but it isn't. I'm not sure what's wrong.

Comment: Check this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/r5mw79bt/

Comment: “Of type” in CSS selectors means “with the same tag name”. E.g., if a container has an `h1` followed by two `p`s, the last `p` will match `:nth-child(3)` (3rd child of the container) and `:nth-of-type(2)` (2nd paragraph in the container).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code:

```
.form-item.fields.phone:nth-of-type(3)
```

Will apply the styles to the third element it finds with these three classes

```
form-item fields phone
```

If you want to modify the first instance of an element with the classes `field text three-digits`, your CSS should be something like this:

```
.field.text.three-digits:nth-of-type(2) {
  background-color: red;
  margin-left: 20%;
}
```

Comment: `.field.text.three-digits {
  background-color: red;
  margin-left: 20%;
}`  works just fine, is when i add ":first-of-type", it stops working

Comment: Apparently this works: `.field.text.three-digits:nth-of-type(2) {
  background-color: red;
  margin-left: 20%;
}`

Comment: Yea that works, but it's confusing you need `nth-of-type(2)` though. Apparently I'm not sure how nth-of-type and nth-child work

Comment: `.something:nth-child(2)` means "any element that has a `.something` class _and_ is the 2nd child in its container". `.something:nth-of-type(2)` means "any element that has a `.something` class _and_ is the 2nd element of its type (i.e. with its tag name) in its container".

Comment: Ilya Streltsyn thanks for the additional information!